# How to to find location (ROI) of a recognized object in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, roi

I was using the tensorflow android example which has a placeholder for the location of a ROI (see tensorflow/examples/android/src/.../Classifier.java), but it is not used.  I would like to be able to locate the ROI of the classified object.  I looked through the code, but it wasn't obvious how the location could be determined.  Does tensorflow support this?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately that placeholder is not populated, and actually determining the region of interest of an object is still a hard research problem. We don't currently have a released example of a model that can do that in TensorFlow, but if you want to look through the research, the term to look for is 'localization'.

There's a related question you might find helpful here:

[Does Convolutional Neural Network possess localization abilities on images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178054/does-convolutional-neural-network-possess-localization-abilities-on-images)