# How to detect an object position in an image with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, analysis

I'm doing a project with Tensorflow which consist in analyzing UML diagrams drawn on a whiteboard or tablet devices to get in the end a file with the correct UML diagram, usable with softwares. The system will also use Machine learning (explaining why we choose Tensorflow).

As the project goes by with researches, my partner and I have been facing a problem : we don't know how to detect object positions in a picture with Tensorflow. We made some researches and found some articles talking about it, but no real conclusion available. We eventually met [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406792/how-to-to-find-location-roi-of-a-recognized-object-in-tensorflow) but we're left with no real tracks on what to do.

Our real question is more about : is there anything new since that (because Tensorflow is upgrading pretty fast in my opinion)? Could we have some articles/hints on what to do then?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found anything that can be used? Current implementations work OK with real world images but cannot be used with computer generated (syntetic) ones such as UML or CAD. I'm interesting in the latter but it seems that a bespoken not ML solution is better than a ML one

Comment: @PaoloV Yeah, the answer provided is pretty useful and fulfil every expectation I had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at this work : https://github.com/Russell91/TensorBox and the associated [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04878v3.pdf).